# Dealing with IPython Cluster Node Death

Tags: ipython-parallel

When using the [cluster mode in Ipython](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/), how does the master deal with the death of a node machine or process?

Specifically if I do an asynchronous apply and some machines die, is there any mechanism to detect this and alert me (by alert I mean is there something I can poll on the result object)?

Is there any mechanism to resubmit these Jobs?